# Какое число использовать после выражения, подобного "и то, и другое"?

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология

К примеру:
**Довериться можно и Петру, и Андерю: и тот, и другой — *человек ответственный / люди ответственные*.**
Или:
**С точки зрения русского языка нет разницы между компьютером и диваном: и то, и это — *конкретное(ые) существительное(ые)*.**

Мне кажется, есть разница между *"и то и другое"* в значении *"оба"* и *"и то, и другое"* в значении перечислительном. *"И тот и другой на выходных не брались за учебники"*, но *"И тот, и другой на выходных не брался за учебники".* Однако я не уверен.

Comment: Розенталь: При повторяющемся союзе сказуемое обычно ставится в форме множественного числа.

Comment: @oleedd,, вы все знаете, скажите, пожалуйста, можно при наличии отрицания использовать союз И...И, а не НИ...НИ?  И вот у Розенталя при наличии союза НИ…НИ  возможна двоякая форма согласования.

Comment: @Sharon При подлежащих можно (тогда отрицание слабее): *И звери, и птицы не любят сидеть в клетках.* И далеко не всегда (смотрю, что зависит от глагола). Но проблема в том, что *и... и* редко звучит (и используется, как следствие) при подлежащих. Сложно даже пример придумать (без "и тот и другой" и т.п.).

Comment: @oleedd Спасибо, а теорию не знаете где почитать?

Comment: @Sharon Дал бы сразу, если бы имел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Сложный вопрос вы задали.** Во-первых, для меня неясна ситуация с союзами И… И и НИ… НИ.
2. Во-вторых, для некоторых примеров **ответы по слуху** мне кажутся очевидными, например:

Довериться можно и Петру, и Андрею: и тот, и другой — **люди ответственные**. С точки зрения русского языка нет разницы между компьютером и диваном: и то, и это — **конкретные существительные**.

3. Теперь **о разнице** между «и то и другое» и «и то, и другое» я думаю, что разница есть, но, возможно, она не всегда проявляется. Кроме того, союз НИ…НИ мне кажется более подходящим.

Ни тот ни другой (= оба) на выходных **не брались** за учебники.
Ни тот, ни другой  (по отдельности) на выходных **не брался** за учебники.

4. **А это Розенталь** (у него дана зависимость от различных **внешних факторов** для  НИ…НИ):  [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_08](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_08)

При наличии союза НИ возможна двоякая форма согласования, например:

(1) Ни он, ни она слова не промолвили... (Тургенев) (принадлежность подлежащих к различному грамматическому роду); ни он, ни я не искали этой встречи (Б. Полевой) (влияет значение лица);

(2) Ни сжатие, ни охлаждение не помогло; Ни отсутствие одних, ни присутствие других не изменило хода дела (подлежащие выражены отвлеченными существительными); И никакой ни черт ни дьявол не имеет права учить меня... (Чехов) (смысловая близость подлежащих и влияние слова никакой).

5. **А это примеры** из Нацкорпуса с формой **ед. числа** для сказуемого при **повторяющемся** союзе НИ… НИ.

Вот ни тот, ни другой папочка **не понимает**, что эти двое ― семья.

Понять, как реально ведется бизнес в этих странах, ни тот, ни другой способ описания **не помогает.**

Ни тот, ни другой ответ **не сделает** изображение более глубоким или осмысленным.

Но ни тот, ни другой в нашем писательском союзе **не замечен.**

Здесь каждый однородный член рассматривается **в отдельности** и задает **ед. число**: *Вот ни тот папочка не понимает, ни другой папочка не понимает…*

Но сказуемое стоит **во мн. числе** для значения «оба»: О пленниках напрочь забыли, им можно было преспокойно подняться и уйти, но вот только ни тот ни другой об этом **не знали**.

6. А вообще говоря, у Розенталя **главным фактором** для мн. числа (как я думаю) является **препозиция однородных членов** – в этом случае мы заранее предполагаем сказуемое во мн. числе. Но в ряде случаев приходится учитывать другие факторы.

Таким образом, вопросов больше, чем ответов.

Comment: А если так: "И тот, и другой на выходных читал учебник"? Звучит кривовато, но тут проблема, что если написать "И тот, и другой на выходных читали учебники", то непонятно, каждый читал по одному учебнику или каждый по несколько учебников. // При этом мне почему-то кажется на слух, что в женском роде единственное число звучит уместнее, чем в мужском: "И та, и другая на выходных читала учебник". Нет у вас такого ощущения?

Comment: Сочетание устойчивое. "Тот" на "этот" не меняется. Поэтому сомнительна правильность его разделения. Больше как разговорный вариант. А что говорят правила?

Comment: @Nektoid И тот, и другой (по отдельности) на выходных читал учебник. И та, и другая на выходных читала учебник.  Здесь ед. число в обоих случаях,  повторяющийся союз предполагает совершение действие каждым cубъектом в отдельности. А ситуация (коммуникативный план) всегда говорящим известна – речь идет о вполне конкретном учебнике,  который задано было прочитать каждому из учеников.

Comment: @oleedd
Сочетание «и тот () и другой» на практике встречается в обоих вариантах, у Розенталя говорится о смысловом единстве при отсутствии запятой, но это единство автор определяет по ситуации, по структуре предложения. Фразеологизмы: и так и сяк, и так и этак – перечислены у Розенталя). Но даже фразеологизмы неустойчивы и при определенных условиях могут писаться через запятую. Сочетание «и тот, и этот» используется, но значительно реже.

Comment: @Sharon Это не тот случай, когда правильно то, что используется. Это как в случае с несочетаемостью слов. Правило новое, поэтому в Нацкорпусе много примеров с запятой. Для перечисления оно плохо подходит. "И тот, и этот" подходит лучше. О, уже даже знаю почему. При перечислении нужна однородность. Слова "тот" и "другой" не очень однородны.

Comment: @oleeddn Конструкции разные, my dear,  читайте Русскую грамматику. Повторяющийся союз И...И с перечислением имеет свои свойства, которые утрачиваются при отсутствии запятой. Там у нас получается заурядный одиночный соединительный союз И + частица И.  А однородными считаются оба варианта.  А у вас вечно форма правит содержанием.

Comment: @Sharon К чему вы это написали? Там сказано о возможности двух вариантов? Если так, то скажите номер параграфа. Говорю про целесообразность перечисления. "Другой" выпадает из однородности: *и тот, и второй* (сойдёт); *и первый, и другой* (не сойдёт).

Comment: Да говорили мы уже с вами про союзы И...И, http://rusgram.ru/Сочинительные_союзы#21  Или у меня почитайте https://proza.ru/2020/10/14/1013  Раздел 5,  ТЕМА 1 .ПОВТОРЯЮЩИЕСЯ СОЮЗ «И…И» И «НИ…НИ»  ПРИ ТЕСНОМ СМЫСЛОВОМ ЕДИНСТВЕ

Comment: Смысловое единство и устойчивое сочетание (что у нас) — разные вещи. При смысловом единстве (там третье не добавить) да. И вообще: кто перечисляет через местоимения в одном роде? Разве что пальцем указывать при этом. При перечислении необходимо, чтобы каждый элемент был чётко определён. Поэтому у Розенталя нет исключений.

Comment: В Нацкорпусе 370 примеров с «ни тот () ни другой». Пишут по-разному, да и число выбирают скорее по ситуации.  И всё выглядит нормально. У Розенталя это выражение фразеологического характера, запятой нет, а на практике запятая чаще ставится. Так что не нужна писателям ваша подробная регламентация и правила вида «при перечислении необходимо, чтобы каждый элемент был чётко определён».  Вот примеры: Они оба узнали друг друга, но ни тот ни другой не подали вида. [О чём они беседовали, ни тот, ни другой нам не доложились. Поставьте два ударения – и каждый элемент будет четко определен. Делов-то!

Comment: В Нацкорпусе бардак, многих правил не знают, куча ошибок. Определяет не ударение, а указание на предмет. Местоимение ссылается на ближайшее слово, а если местоимений два, то хорошо, если у них разный род (тогда он определяет элемент). Я против двух ударений, разговорный вариант. Потому что сочетание устойчивое, там ничего не изменить. И вообще, слова из разных опер: *этот — тот*; *такой — другой* (качество). Так люди не перечисляют: *этот, тот, другой*.

Comment: Смотрите, что получается. Забираем первый И, чем разрушаем устойчивость, и остаётся как раз чисто перечисление: *Довериться можно и Петру, и Павлу: тот и другой — люди ответственные.* Вот вам настоящее перечисление, оно не подходит.

Comment: Какое же это перечисление без перечислительной интонации?  Союз И объединяет однородные члены в одну фразу, вам ли это не знать!

Comment: Союз И участвует в перечислении тоже: *первый, второй и третий*. Ну давайте так: *Довериться можно и Петру, и Павлу: тот, другой — люди ответственные.*